# Bootstrap modal not closing and refreshing index page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

My edit/update modal isn't working correctly. I want it to update the db, close the modal and return the user back to my index page where the table containing my products should be updated. Right now its just updating the db, but not closing the modal and the user has to refresh the browser to see the updated record. I'm using these gems

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'
```

Here is my index.html.erb

```
...
 <tbody class="product-index">
   <%= render "index" %>
 </tbody>
</table> #starting <table> tag is up higher..
</div>
<div id="product-modal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div id="inner-product-modal" class="modal-content"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my _index partial where the edit link is created:

```
 <% @products.each do |product| %>
<tr>
 <td><%= product.name %></td>
 <td><%= number_to_currency product.price %></td>
 <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path(product), remote: true, class: 
 "btn btn-default" %></td>
 <td><%= link_to "Delete", product_delete_path(product), remote: true, 
 class: "btn btn-danger" %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

This is my products controller's edit and update actions

```
 def edit
     @product = Product.find(params[:id])
 end

 def update
    @products = Product.all
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.update_attributes(product_params)
 end
```

Here is my edit.js.erb file

```
$("#inner-product-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'edit') %>");
$("#product-modal").modal("show")
```

This is my _edit partial

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3><%= "Editing #{@product.name}" %></h3>
</div>
<%= render "form" %>
```

Then finally this is my form partial (edited for brevity)

```
<%= form_for @product, remote: true, html: { class: "form-horizontal", 
style: "display:inline;" } do |f| %>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <ul class="errors"></ul>
....

<div class="modal-footer">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", "#", class: "btn", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to submit your update request with normal `post` method and refresh the page you should remove `remote: true` from your `form_for` helpers.

**Update:**

Do a redirect at the end of your `update` controller action:

```
def update
  @products = Product.all
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @product.update_attributes(product_params)
  redirect_to your_index_path
end
```

Comment: Shoot.. I tried that, but now instead of going to the index page its going to a product page.. I can't tell why?

Comment: @ToddT you have to `redirect` the user at the end of your controller action to index page. See the update answer.

Comment: Awesome!!! Not sure why I missed that one.. Think I was frustrated.. But it works!!! Thank you soo much!